# How to figure out syntax for symbols?

Tags: syntax, symbols, built-in-symbols

I'm new to Mathematica and am having a hard time figuring out how to type certain symbols when I read the documentation.

For example, in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPropertyDistribution.html, the syntax is:

`MatrixPropertyDistribution[expr,x mdist]` where there is a symbol between `x` and `mdist`. I eventually figured out that the symbol could be interpreted as `Distributed[x, mdist]` or `x \[Distributed] mdist`, but is there  a function in Mathematica or some other website (like Detexify for Tex) that can translate the symbol to the thing you would actually need to type in Mathematica to get the symbol?

A similar issue I'm having right now is trying to define the usual complex inner product as is done in first example in the Applications section of this reference: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html. The issue is that the braces they have there is not the same as just the brackets on the keyboard corresponding to pressing Shift with "," or Shift with "." and I'd like to find out how to actually type these certain braces, so I can actually use the inner product.

Comment: Is [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterSpecialCharacters.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: seen [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html)?

Comment: `InputForm` looks like the right thing, but when I run `InputForm[\[Distributed]]` nothing happens (nothing gets returned), and when I run `InputForm[\[LeftAngleBracket]a, b\[RightAngleBracket]]` I just get `\[LeftAngleBracket]a, b\[RightAngleBracket]]` (but all the brackets in symbols). Although now I see that if I just copy and paste it into stackexchange it tells me how to type the symbol...so I guess that works.

Comment: Copy the code and paste it into a notebook. Convert the cell to InputForm and you will see `MatrixPropertyDistribution[ Placeholder[expr], Placeholder[Distributed[x, mdist]]]` Highlight `Distributed` and press `F1` for help.

Comment: Thanks Bob, that works and is more convenient than copy and pasting into stackexchange.

Comment: Why not just selecting the unknown symbol and pressing F1? (This cannot be done in Wolfram Cloud or Wolfram Engine at least now, of course. ) You don't need to convert it to inputform first, the document knows these symbols.

Comment: The "Basic Math Assistant" from the Palettes menu can also help you with this. It allows you to produce these glyphs and also shows the hotkeys for entering them from your keyboard. You will need to click around a bit to find something specific, though.

Comment: I usually enter it with Escape key + 'dist' + Escape key. Its character code appears to be f3d2 and the symbol is in the unicode private use area as 

Comment: Ok, didn't know about the F1 key, that could have a lot of time over the past few days...